# Attempting to shell out commands in sequence through python subprocess

Tags: python

Im attempting to run virtualenv and install packages through pip locally. When running the below routine no output is being given to give me any indication as to why its failing. I am trying to do something similar to the following

`source env/bin/activate`

`(env) pip install [packages]`

I can do it with `Popen("source env/bin/activate && pip install package", shell=True)` but what hoping to handle it in the way I have it defined in my routine.

Any ideas?

```
def install_pkgs(self):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(["source %s" % (os.path.join(self._commons['dst_dir'], 'env/bin/activate'),)],
                            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                            shell=True,
                            executable='/bin/bash')
    proc.stdin.write(str.encode("pip install --upgrade %s\n" % (" ".join(self._loaded_packages),)))
    output, error = proc.communicate()
    print(output)
    print(error)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get `stderr` you should specify `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` or `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` (to redirect it to stdout).

To install/upgrade packages you could try:

```
subprocess.check_call(['/path/to/virtualenv/bin/pip', 'install', '-U'] + packages)
```

Comment: Unfortunately calling it directly still fails to continue the download with pip